# How to display received data on Serial port

Tags: vb.net

I am new to using Visual Basic and just have started coding using the language. 
From simple coding, I want to try something a bit complex such as sending and receiving data through a serial port communication. I was able to go through a lot of tutorials about it and came about trying this code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Dim myPort As Array
    Delegate Sub SetTextCallback(ByVal [text] As String) 'Added to prevent threading errors during receiving of data

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        myPort = IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()
        ComboBox1.Items.AddRange(myPort)

        Button2.Enabled = False

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        SerialPort1.PortName = ComboBox1.Text
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = ComboBox2.Text
        SerialPort1.Open()

        Button1.Enabled = False
        Button2.Enabled = True
        Button3.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        SerialPort1.Write(RichTextBox1.Text & vbCr) 'concatenate with \n

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        SerialPort1.Close()
        Button1.Enabled = True
        Button2.Enabled = False
        Button3.Enabled = False
    End Sub

    Private Sub ReceivedText(ByVal [text] As String) 'input from ReadExisting
        If Me.RichTextBox2.InvokeRequired Then
            Dim x As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf ReceivedText)
            Me.Invoke(x, New Object() {(text)})
        Else
            Me.RichTextBox2.Text &= [text] 'append text
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub SerialPort1_DataReceived(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs) Handles SerialPort1.DataReceived
        ReceivedText(SerialPort1.ReadExisting())
    End Sub
End Class
```

Button1 is designated for Opening the Port while Button2 and Button3 are used to Write and Close the port respectively. The RichTextBox1 is where I can write the data I want to send and the RichTextBox2 is where the data received is displayed. Now my problem is whenever I click the button to Write data on the port nothing displays. I want to ask help on how to get about with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write a message and read it on the same end of the serial communication.

If you want to "fake" the serial communication, so that your pc talks to itself, you have 2 solutions:

1. Use some nullmodem emulator to virtually create COM ports pairs that are connected through software. Software like [com0com](http://com0com.sourceforge.net/), does just what you are looking for, but sometimes is a bit tricky makings thingks work well at the start.
2. Another solution is to have 2 serial ports in your pc (with an usb
   adapter for example) and connect the TRx pin of the sending port to the RDx pin
   of the reading port, and the RDx pin of the sending port to the TRx pin
   of the reading port. All other pins just 1 to 1. Then you can also read from write from one port and read from the other.

Both approaches do the same, the first through software, the second physically.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45180578/how-to-display-received-data-on-serial-port/45180773#45180773) you have another SO question about that, where you can get more info. Also google "faking Serial ports" should help.